# Categorize hex color into red, green, blue, yellow, orange,

Tags: php, colors, hex

Is there a way to easily assign a given hex color code to a more general category (red, gren, blue, yellow, orange, pink, black, white, grey, ...)?

Like `#ffcc55` -> orange, `#f0f0f0` -> white, ...

EDIT: or even just similar to adobe photoshop finding the nearest web safe color, so it would reduce the number of colors to 256, would be already a great solution!

Comment: Ahem... finding the nearest color can be done quite easier, I think, especially if you have the table of web-safe color RGB values readyJust calculate the difference (it's hexadecimals, remember), then choose the color with the lowest one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php, comment from cory at lavacube dot com:

```
<?php

function color_mkwebsafe ( $in )
{
    // put values into an easy-to-use array
    $vals['r'] = hexdec( substr($in, 0, 2) );
    $vals['g'] = hexdec( substr($in, 2, 2) );
    $vals['b'] = hexdec( substr($in, 4, 2) );

    // loop through
    foreach( $vals as $val )
    {
        // convert value
        $val = ( round($val/51) * 51 );
        // convert to HEX
        $out .= str_pad(dechex($val), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    return $out;
}

?>
```

Example: color_mkwebsafe('0e5c94');
Produces: 006699

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a php guru so there may be more efficient ways of solving this in php, but I'd set up each color as an array, so you've got 3 numbers for each color category.  Then find the mathematical distance between your proposed color and each of the others. Save the closest match and return the name of it.

```
function getcolorname($mycolor) {
    // mycolor should be a 3 element array with the r,g,b values 
    // as ints between 0 and 255. 
    $colors = array(
        "red"       =>array(255,0,0),
        "yellow"    =>array(255,255,0),
        "green"     =>array(0,255,0),
        "cyan"      =>array(0,255,255),
        "blue"      =>array(0,0,255),
        "magenta"   =>array(255,0,255),
        "white"     =>array(255,255,255),
        "grey"      =>array(127,127,127),
        "black"     =>array(0,0,0)
    );

    $tmpdist = 255*3;
    $tmpname = "none";
    foreach($colors as $colorname => $colorset) {        
        $r_dist = (pow($mycolor[0],2) - pow($colorset[0],2));
        $g_dist = (pow($mycolor[1],2) - pow($colorset[1],2));       
        $b_dist = (pow($mycolor[2],2) - pow($colorset[2],2));
        $totaldist = sqrt($r_dist + $g_dist + $b_dist);
        if ($totaldist < $tmpdist) {        
            $tmpname = $colorname;
            $tmpdist = $totaldist;
        }
    }
    return $tmpname;
}
```

Comment: Ah - I may have misunderstood the question - I thought the goal was to map from a hex value to a string description, rather than from a hex value to one of a subset of similar hex values.

Comment: no problem, appreciated very much your help!! :) btw, your function always returns red for me, no matter which color I try? :)

Comment: I just edited it - I forgot the $ in front of the 'r_dist','g_dist' and 'b_dist' variables when I summed them up.  Looks like it's working now.

Comment: cool, does the order of the list matter (the array)? If you want to add new color ranges such as e.g. orange?

Comment: The order of the list doesn't matter, but as it gets longer it'll get a little less efficient... I'm probably doing too much math here.  There's probably a better algorithm.  If you're only doing this for yourself or a small group of users, it's probably fine.  If you want a million people running this, it'll probably chug a bit.

Comment: oh, cool, thx! well, I thought to iterate through all the hex color combinations (convert them to rgb for your script) and insert the results into a db, so you can query for the "color-group" for each color...

Comment: probably there's an error, since if you try this color: #92D050 (which is a green color), red => 146 green => 208 and blue => 80. You can see that the distance from red is negative. Depending on values you can get a sqrt of a negative number which results in NAN value and you got strange results. Such as that #92D050 is a Green, which is not true.